# Change CIDR Block of EC2 Instance AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, ip, ip-address, cidr

My question is is there a way to change the CIDR block of an EC2 instance after it was made? Like i want to change its CIDR to be able to connect to another VPC which happens to have the same CIDR block and that is causing issues, so i need to change the CIDR block of one of the EC2 instances to be able to connect them both.

Thanks in advance for any help or guidance.

Cheers!

Answer (score 0):

You can launch an instance in any subnet that is provided by the VPC. The subnet is what controls which CIDR block (IP address range) the instance is assigned. You need to terminate the instance and launch in a different subnet.

You cannot change it on the fly. You do have to terminate and relaunch.